# An ajax function throwing XHR faild loading

Tags: ajax, laravel, token, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to like posts without refreshing page and I wrote a little script inside the page, here it is:

```
var token = '{{ Session::token() }}';

$(document).on('click', '.inspire_button', function () {

    var content_id = $(this).data('content_id');
    var urlInspiring = '{{  route('inspiring') }}';

    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $.ajax({
        url: urlInspiring,
        method: "POST",
        data:{
            content_id:content_id,
            _token:token
        },
        success:function (data) {
            if(data == 'done'){
                load_stuff();
            }
        }

    })
});
```

As you can see, I added token into var, before the button was clicked, Than I pass it with the data. It still throws me an error:

> XHR failed loading

I always have the problem in laravel when trying to pass data with ajax. and it's always token error.

> POST http://localhost/yazilimhaber/public/inspiring 500 (Internal Server Error)
>   XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost/yazilimhaber/public/inspiring".

Comment: Try the url as `var urlInspiring = '{{  route("inspiring") }}';`

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: I tried it, still giving same excact error

Comment: yeah it shows the `token `content

Comment: What exactly is the error shown in the response?

Comment: Ok I found the reason, irrelated with ajax. I will drop the answer below for users who come across the same problem

Comment: I was doing `Auth::user()->id();` instead `Auth::user()->id;`

Answer (score 0):

In my controller, I was calling to `Auth::user()->id();` which was supposed to be
 `Auth::user()->id;`, To spot such issues.
 
You can go network > preview tab, It throws the errors in there which was caused by ajax